# How to serialize Rsa signing credentials in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core

I am trying to make oauth authorization in my ASP.NET 5 web application. I have tried this aproach:

[ASP.NET 5 OAuthBearerAuthentication: The following authentication scheme was not accepted: Bearer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998052/asp-net-5-oauthbearerauthentication-the-following-authentication-scheme-was-not)

And it works well, but as you can see the rsa keys are always generated on startup. As i've experienced and seen in other topics, `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString` and `RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString` are not present in DNX Core, and i could not find any other ways to (de)serialize my once generated credentials. Can you please show me a method?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just upgraded my project to ASP.NET Core RC2 and ran into this issue as I read my RSA key (stored as XML) out of a config file for my JWT token generation.

I ended up creating my own method extensions to replace the ones I was using with ASP.NET 5 RC1. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Xml;

namespace RSACryptoServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static class RSACryptoServiceProviderExtensions
    {
        public static void FromXmlString(this RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa, string xmlString)
        {
            RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);

            if (xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name.Equals("RSAKeyValue"))
            {
                foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
                {
                    switch (node.Name)
                    {
                        case "Modulus":     parameters.Modulus =    Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "Exponent":    parameters.Exponent =   Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "P":           parameters.P =          Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "Q":           parameters.Q =          Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "DP":          parameters.DP =         Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "DQ":          parameters.DQ =         Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "InverseQ":    parameters.InverseQ =   Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                        case "D":           parameters.D =          Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText); break;
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid XML RSA key.");
            }

            rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);
        }

        public static string ToXmlString(this RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa)
        {
            RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

            return string.Format("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>{0}</Modulus><Exponent>{1}</Exponent><P>{2}</P><Q>{3}</Q><DP>{4}</DP><DQ>{5}</DQ><InverseQ>{6}</InverseQ><D>{7}</D></RSAKeyValue>",
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Modulus),
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Exponent),
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.P),
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Q),
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.DP),
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.DQ),
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.InverseQ),
                Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.D));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though, really, in .NET Core you should operate on `RSA` instead of `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, since RSACryptoServiceProvider is Windows-non-UWP-only.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Csp/src/System/Security/Cryptography/RSACryptoServiceProvider.cs) in the CoreFX has `ImportParameters` and `ExportParameters` methods which deserialize/serialize using the [`RSAParameters`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/RSAParameters.cs) struct.