# asp.net mvc core - equivalent of User.IsSignedIn()

Tags: asp.net-core

I am migrating a web application over to the new `asp.net core` model, and have hit a sudden snag with one of the views.

I cannot find the migrated equivalent to `User` and `User.IsSignedIn()` under the new model - when used in views, like this...

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@if (User.IsSignedIn())
{
}
```

I've tried importing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor` library, where I thought it would be held, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The approach adopted by the ASP.NET team for RC2 is to use `SignInManager.IsSignedIn`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Mvc.Server.Models

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) {
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else {
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Where does the value of User come from?

Comment: I try this, and it says "User" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: That's likely due to the fact you're using RC2 packages: VS still relies on RC1 tooling, and is unable to access the properties exposed by the base view page class. You can safely ignore this error ;)

Comment: I feel like "safely ignoring errors" is the mantra of dot net core. >:( - I am so ready for the updating tooling!!!

Comment: Hehe yeah, that's the price to pay for living on the bleeding edge :)

Comment: Worth noting that `SignInManager` is part of ASP.net identity.  If you're not using identity, this won't work.

Answer (score 22):

Looking at the migration docs I think this might do it:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{ 
 ...
}
```

Found here: http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingauthmembership.html

Comment: This was it, indeed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the earlier answers are not always correct, because it depends on what "signed in" means. In Core, the IPrincipal is a ClaimsPrincipal. While it has an Identity property, which is of the type ClaimsIdentity, it's simply the first object in the Identities property collection. This is largely for backwards compatibility for the old ASP.NET. In the new world, no one identity is necessarily authoritative over the others... they're all valid.

Each of those identities has an IsAuthenticated property. You could, for example, have an identity that simply is tracking an anonymous user with some claims attached to it, so whatever created the identity would likely have set IsAuthenticated to false. On the other hand, the plumbing for the Cookie auth sets it to true when you've called a sign in method, but again, it depends on which identity a particular part of your app is paying attention to.

Also, in the RTM version, there is no IsSignedIn.

Comment: Jeff have you checked `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L110) which is used by MVC-Core templates ? It looks like any `ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme` is considered logged in.

Comment: Yes, I do see that exists now. Remember though, this assumes that you want to take a dependency on the Identity package. Identity can handle all of the plumbing and persistence of user data, but if you want to role your own, you need only Security.